# Convert regular expression to CFG

Tags: regex, grammar, automata

How can I convert some regular language to its equivalent Context Free Grammar?
Is it necessary to construct the DFA corresponding to that regular expression or is there some rule for such a conversion?

For example, consider the following regular expression

> 01+10(11)<sup>*</sup>

How can I describe the grammar corresponding to the above RE?

Comment: wondering whether there are any open source library implementations helpful for this task by now

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- Change A+B to grammar

  ```
  G -> A
  G -> B
  ```
- Change A* to

  ```
  G -> (empty)
  G -> A G
  ```
- Change AB to

  ```
  G -> AB
  ```

and proceed recursively on A and B. Base cases are empty language (no productions) and a single symbol.

In your case

```
 A -> 01
 A -> 10B
 B -> (empty)
 B -> 11B
```

If the language is described by finite automaton:

- use states as nonterminal symbols
- use language as set of terminal symbols
- add a transition p -> aq for any transition p -> q on letter a in the original automaton
- use initial state as initial symbol in the grammar

Comment: Why is **B -> 11** instead of **B -> B11**?

Comment: Why are you changing `A+B` into `G -> A` and `G -> B`? Doesn't `+` mean "one or more of the previous expression" in regex?

Comment: @LeonOverweel In formal language theory `A+B` is used to denote sum, in programming languages notation `A|B` is used instead.

Answer (score 6):

I guess you mean convert it to a formal grammar with rules of the form V->w, where V is a nonterminal and w is a string of terminals/nonterminals.  To start, you can simply say (mixing CFG and regex syntax):

```
S -> 01+10(11)*
```

Where S is the start symbol.  Now let's break it up a bit (and add whitespace for clarity):

```
S -> 0 A 1 0 B
A -> 1+
B -> (11)*
```

The key is to convert `*`es and `+`es to recursion.  First, we'll convert the Kleene star to a plus by inserting an intermediate rule that accepts the empty string:

```
S -> 0 A 1 0 B
A -> 1+
B -> (empty)
B -> C
C -> (11)+
```

Finally, we'll convert `+` notation to recursion:

```
S -> 0 A 1 0 B
A -> 1
A -> A 1
B -> (empty)
B -> C
C -> 11
C -> C 11
```

To handle `x?`, simply split it into a rule producing empty and a rule producing x .

Answer (score 2):

Actually, different CFG grammars can produce the same language. So given a regular expression (regular language), its mapping back a CFG is not unique.

Definitely, you can construct a CFG that result in a given regular expression. The above answers shown some ways to achieve this.

Hope this gives you a high level idea.

Answer (score 0):

For the example, the following grammar is equivalent:

```
S -> 01|10A
A -> 11A|empty
```